# Job in spring batch is getting executed multiple times and not stopping

Tags: java, xml, jdbc, cassandra, spring-batch

I am trying to read data from cassandra using spring batch, where I have implemented ItemReader, ItemProcessor, and ItemWriter. I am able to read the data , process it and write back the data to the same table. I am creating xml file to execute the job:

xml:

```
    <job id="LoadStatusIndicator" job-repository="jobRepository" restartable="false">
        <step id="LoadStatus" next="">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="StatusReader" processor="ItemProcessor" writer="ItemWriter"
                    commit-interval="10" />
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>

    <beans:bean id="ItemWriter" scope="step"
        class="com.batch.writer.ItemWriter">
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="ItemProcessor" scope="step"
        class="com.batch.processor.ItemProcessor">
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="Reader" scope="step"
        class="com.reader.ItemReader">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="CassandraSource" />

    </beans:bean>
```

applicationcontext.xml:

```
<beans:bean id="CassandraSource" parent="DataSourceParent">
<beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:cassandra://${cassandra.hostName}:${cassandra.port}/${cassandra.keyspace}" />
<beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver" />
</beans:bean>
```

reader class:

```
   public static final String query = "SELECT * FROM test_1 allow filtering;";

 @Override
    public List<Item> read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException 
    {
    List<Item> results = new ArrayList<Item>();
try {
results = cassandraTemplate.select(query,Item.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
return results;
    }
```

writer classs:

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends Item> item) throws Exception {
    try {
    cassandraTemplate.insert(item);
}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

But the problem is the whole job is getting executed multiple times , infact it is not stopping at all. I have to force stop the job execution. I have only 2 rows in the table.
I think it is because of the commit-interval defined in xml, but having commit-interval = 10, job executes more than 10 times

According to my understanding, when I run the xml file that means I am running the job only one time, it calls the reader once keeps the data in the run time memory (job repository), calls item processor once (I use list ) and the whole list is inserted at once

Comment: Does this also happen if you remove all the jdbc/cassandra related code?

Comment: Yes, it doesnot stop even if I remove cassandra related codes

Comment: in my opinion the problem is with non-needed <tasklet> configuration.  I think you can simply omit it.

Comment: I would remove the next="" as there is no next step. Also, as you append to the existing table, aren't you creating new items that your reader can read, creating an infinite loop ?

Comment: @Ilya Dyoshin. I think to chunk the step we need to have tasklet, and I need chunking because @ later point of time my data will be huge

Comment: @Philippe I tried removing next="" and it doesn't make any difference. Either u do not define next="" as a property or u keep it null

Comment: Do I need to close the jdbc connection in the writer when I have inserted the data??

Comment: I cleared every thing from the reader processor and writer, and just put a simple sysout and the job is executing ony one time. @ Mark Rotteveel  you were right this doesnot happen if I remove all the jdbc/cassandra related code. Previously I only commented                                                                          results = cassandraTemplate.select(query, Item.class);   Now I removed everything. and it worked but how do I get the data from cassandra ???

Comment: Is it because I am using reader class and inside reader class I am using cassandra template to execute the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

In reader class I wrote:

`if (results.size!=0)
return results;
else 
return null;`